# Additional field on django rest framework filters and form (not stored)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There are 2 scenarios here where I'm looking to add an additional non-stored field to the DRF 3.0 generics views.  On both my add contact and list contacts web services I was able to call these correctly using python as client.  I would like to be able to the same functionality possible in the browser though as well.

For add contact I need to add a scenario ('phone', 'form') so I can have different validations take placed based on this value.

For the list contacts, I have an interesting data scenario where I want to check 2 fields and related table for the phone number...so on this I'd just like to be able to add a field with name search_phone to the filters on the list view so I can handle it in get_queryset.

I tried adding a field to ModelSerializer but I couldn't get it in the form or filter.

TIA

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).(drfdocs)

Comment: Have you read about `write_only` fields in DRF? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only
Yes, they are available to write to during POST, but not during serializing to representation; as a consequence; not during your response.
However, you can combine this with the `serializer.context`
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context

For example: You could take the `write_only` field and set the `context` on the serializer and use that in filtering perhaps
Do some reading here and see if you can figure out a workable solution.